# AutoHotKey WinText to close certain window (error) when WinTitle is duplicated

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I am trying to make an autohotkey script that automatically kills an error screen on a program (as it schedules a lot and it blocks all the scheduled items), but the error has the same title name as the actual program, so I can't use the below script:

```
Loop {
    WinActive, IBM Cognos Impromptu
    WinClose, IBM Cognos Impromptu }
```

I know there is something you can do with WinText, but somehow I can't make it work.
It should only kill the window if the WinText is 'Error retrieving data from the database.'.

Does anybody know if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Silly as it sounds, I got it to work with:

```
Loop
{
    WinWait, IBM Cognos Impromptu, Error retrieving dat
    WinClose, IBM Cognos Impromptu, Error retrieving dat
}
```

Got the inspiration from [user3419297's post](https://superuser.com/a/861340/53590), so thanks! :)